# QGIS 3.8 Python merge files

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, python-3

For a merge operation I need a list of all my layers in the TOC with path and filename. How can I achieve that?

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers() # dictionary
myLyrList[]
for layer in layers.values():
   print(layer.name())
#Here I need a List of the my layers in the toc with the path and the filename
processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':['/home/lissiklaus/Downloads/2.shp|layername=2','/home/lissiklaus/Downloads/3.shp'],'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:31468'),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with following modifications in your script.

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers() # dictionary

for layer in layers.values():
   print(layer.name())

list_layers = list(layers.values())

crs = list_layers[0].crs()

#Here I need a List of the my layers in the toc with the path and the filename
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", 
                             {'LAYERS':list_layers,
                             'CRS':crs,
                             'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

I tried above script out and it worked as expected.

Comment: just excat what I need gracias!

Comment: So, can you mark this answer as accepted?  Thanks.